# Background Audio not working in iOS10,iOS11 on simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, avplayer, avaudioplayer

App is not playing audio in background mode in ios simulator, it is working fine for device. But I need to test on iPhone X.

Comment: have you enable background mode from Targets -> Capabilities -> Background Mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue in the iOS 11 simulator.  Apps which support background audio are getting incorrectly suspended.

This is not an issue in earlier simulators as they do not support suspending the iOS applications when backgrounded.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed in iOS 11.2 simulator, available since Xcode 9.2 (currently beta).

Comment: Either it was never actually fixed or this bug has been re-introduced in the iOS 11.3 simulator.

Comment: @George I just tested on iOS 11.3 simulator and it is working. You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you wait for at least 3 minutes after backgrounding your app to confirm it wasn't suspended?

Comment: @George yes, 6 minutes, backgrounded, locked, still playing